# Mvc3 FileResult and FileStreamResult error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I have this controller action that returns a pdf document:

```
  public FileResult getPdf()
  {
         System.IO.FileStream  fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("myFile.pdf");         
         byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)fileStream.Length];
         fileStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
         Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;");
         return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
  }
```

That code works ok with a ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download File","getPdf")
```

but not work with:

```
 <embed id="PdfFile" type="application/pdf" src="/Home/getPdf"/>
```

or

```
<object id="PdfFile" type="application/pdf" src="/Home/getPdf"/>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#someDiv").load('/Home/getPdf');
    });
</script>
```

**That 3 options works fine from visual studio self host, but when I deploy to IIS7 return "Error 404 not found". ActionLink is also working properly in IIS7**

The folders have permissions for all users.

I also tried with FileStreamResult and HttpResponse.binaryWrite. (Same results)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay this should give you what your looking for

```
 <object data="src="@Url.Action("GetPDF")"" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
alt : <a href="data/test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
 </object>


 public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
 {
     FileStream fs = new FileStream("filename.pdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     return File(fs, "application/pdf");
 }
```

Comment: I'm trying to display a pdf document in a partial view, from a controller. So cant use a form.